# search element in a field of a mongodb collection using pyhton

Tags: python, arrays, mongodb, search, numbers

I need to search for a number that is in a field of a collection I am using python and mongodb
The collection has a prov_oid field and in the field the numbers 8,9,13,17,23,24,1,25,26,28,33,40,41,51,52,53,54 are stored in this way

Comment: see [`$in`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/query/in/) or aggregate [`$in`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/in/)

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.